# How to: Simple Nested Shortcode

Tags: shortcode

Im trying to wrap a shortcode inside of a "user loggeed in" shortcode. Here are the two shortcodes and my setup in WYSIWYG

```
function wpfc_logged_in( $atts, $content = null ) {
    if (is_user_logged_in() )
      {
        return do_shortcode($content);
      }
}

add_shortcode('loggedin', 'wpfc_logged_in');


function info_box( $atts, $content = null  ) {
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'type' => 'tip',
        'icon' => ''
    ), $atts ) );  
    $return = '<div id="info-box"><div class="info-box '.$type.'"><p>'.$content.'</p><a href="#" class="info-close-icon"></a></div></div>';
    return $return; 
}
add_shortcode('info_box', 'info_box');
```

WYSIWYG:

```
[loggedin]
[ info_box type='setting' ]content text[ /info_box]
[/loggedin]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you have extra spaces in your shortcodes.

Try

```
[loggedin]
[info_box type='setting']content text[/info_box]
[/loggedin]
```

instead of

```
[loggedin]
[ info_box type='setting' ]content text[ /info_box]
[/loggedin]
```

Comment: Holy cow! Thank you lolz. I have to wait 3 mins to accept the answer. Ugh this was driving me nuts!

Comment: ok great, so your code was fine after all ;-)